# In ruby 1.9.3., how can an object created by: object-instance.clone not find a method which the original object could?

Tags: ruby, clone

I am relatively new to Ruby but fluent in many other languages. As part of my Ruby learning, I have a reference to an object created by:  `some_instance.clone`. The original object instance can find a certain method OK, but the cloned object instance cannot. How can this happen? What is the proper way to understand `clone` if the copy is so different that it cannot invoke a method of the underlying base class?

Code:

```
  board1 = Board.new(true)
  board1.checkBoardLayout

  board2 = Board.clone
  log.debug("board1 #{board1.object_id}, board2 #{board2.object_id}")
  board2.checkBoardLayout
```

The first invocation of `checkBoardLayout` succeeds; the second one fails with

```
 undefined method `checkBoardLayout' for #
```

In what way is my understanding deficient; isn't it a valid expectation that `clone` will behave similar to the original? If so, what is going on: why doesn't it work? If not, then in what sense can it be any kind of clone? `dup` is no better. Is my Ruby corrupted?

Answer (score 3):

`Board.clone` clones the class, not an instance. Therefore the error is correct, since you try to send `checkBoardLayout` to a class and not to an instance of that class.

What you want to try is:

```
board2 = board1.clone
```

or

```
board2 = Board.new(true).clone
```

Btw. it is best practice in Ruby not to use snake case in method names, please use underscores instead: `check_board_layout`